# multiple nginx 'if' query_string rewrites not behaving properly

Tags: redirect, nginx, get

Been trying to add these rewrites for 301 re-directs. The first URL works perfectly. but the second and third rewrites result in redirecting to the new URL but they maintain the queries (I don't need the queries after the page name).

```
if ($query_string ~ "^prodID=1043&catID=1&subCatID=3"){ rewrite ^/?product.php$ https://www.example.com/products.html? permanent; }
if ($query_string ~ "^prodID=1050&catID=1&subCatID=3"){ rewrite ^/?product.php$ https://www.example.com/products.html? permanent; }
if ($query_string ~ "^userID=1053&catID=1&subCatID=3"){ rewrite ^/?user.php$ https://www.example.com/users.html? permanent; }
```

they should all re-direct to

1. https://www.example.com/products.html
2. https://www.example.com/products.html
3. https://www.example.com/users.html

But instead they re-direct to

- https://www.example.com/products.html
- https://www.example.com/products.html?prodID=1050&catID=1&subCatID=3
- https://www.example.com/users.html?userID=1053&catID=1&subCatID=3

log files are showing normal redirects: 301 GET /products.php?prodID=1050&catID=1&subCatID=3 HTTP/1.1 "

Can anyone help? I cannot find a solution yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) ?

Comment: Yes,  this is why I've posted the problem as I was hoping someone had a better way of writing it. I'm still hunting down a better solution to what I've written. I have 250 rewrites to create. So I'm still working on tying to find a better script

Comment: A standard rewrite isn't working... `rewrite ^/product.php?prodID=1050&catID=1&subCatID=3 /products.html? permanent;`

Comment: Can you describe what happens on a standard rewrite ? This may be link to the fact that you "rewrite .php to .HTML"